Migrating project using angular 15 to angular 17
Can we directly able to migrate from  angular v15 to angular v17 by using ngupdate command or first we need to do v16
I'm using node version 16 as of now. I'm trying to update angular 17.
I want to know like if we are using angular 15 application and we tried to move that project to angular 17 . How can we do that.

What I would do is to just try and see what breaks. That's what unit tests are for. Otherwise, there should be a changelog. the docs say that you should indeed do 15->16 and then 16->17
